# AJAX JQuery POST Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am unable to read the POST values I expect in my PHP script. The request goes through it just does not serialize the data properly into the POST request aspect of it all. **There is a moderate amount of code and I would rather you skip this than downvote it as I need help desperately and I know many of you do not wish to spend your time answering this long of a question.**

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/core/enrollphase1.php" id="enrollPhase1" method="post" name="enrollPhase1">
        <select class="inputGeneral" id="SecurityQuestion1" style="font-size:20px;">
            <option value="1">
                What is your favorite book?
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                What is your favorite movie?
            </option>
            <option value="3">
                What is your favorite TV show?
            </option>
            <option value="4">
                What is your pet's name?
            </option>
            <option value="5">
                What is your favorite hobby?
            </option>
        </select><br>
        <br>
        <input class="inputGeneral" id="SecurityAnswer1" type="text"><br>
        <br>
        <select class="inputGeneral" id="SecurityQuestion2" style="font-size:20px;">
            <option value="1">
                What is your favorite book?
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                What is your favorite movie?
            </option>
            <option value="3">
                What is your favorite TV show?
            </option>
            <option value="4">
                What is your pet's name?
            </option>
            <option value="5">
                What is your favorite hobby?
            </option>
        </select><br>
        <br>
        <input class="inputGeneral" id="SecurityAnswer2" type="text"><br>
        <br>
        <input class="inputGeneral" type="submit" value="Continue">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### JQuery and AJAX:

```
  $(document).arrive("#enrollPhase1", function() {
  // Auto Correct Questions
  $("#SecurityQuestion1").on("change", function() {
      if(this.value === $("#SecurityQuestion2").val()) {
        // Notify that same question will not fly with us
      } else {
        // If something changes and they are no longer the same, remove all errors
      }
  })

  $("#SecurityQuestion2").on("change", function() {
    if(this.value === $("#SecurityQuestion1").val()) {
      // Notify that same question will not fly with us
    } else {
      // If something changes and they are no longer the same, remove all errors
    }
  })

  // Get EnrollPhase1 Form...
  var EnrollPhase1Form = $('#enrollPhase1');

  $(EnrollPhase1Form).submit(function(event) {
    // Catch Browser Submitting Form
    event.preventDefault();

    // Temp Hold Security Question IDs to check for same question
    var SQ1 = $("#SecurityQuestion1").find(":selected").val();
    var SQ2 = $("#SecurityQuestion2").find(":selected").val();

    if(SQ1 === SQ2) {
      // Same question issue 
      return;
    }

    // Temp Hold Security Question Answers to check for same answer
    var SA1 = $("#SecurityAnswer1").val();
    var SA2 = $("#SecurityAnswer2").val();

    if(SA1 === SA2) {
      // Same answer issue
      return;
    }

    // Hide UsernameForm...
    $("#enrollPhase1Container").hide();

    // Error Message Response Removal
    $(".success, .error, .warning, .info").remove();

    // Start animationSpin
    $("#animationSpin").removeClass("hidden");

    // Serialize the form data
    alert(JSON.stringify(EnrollPhase1Form));
    var formData = $(EnrollPhase1Form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: $(EnrollPhase1Form).attr('method'),
        url: $(EnrollPhase1Form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,

        statusCode: {
          500: function() {
            // Done animationSpin
            $("#animationSpin").addClass("hidden");

            // Error Message Callback
            $(".status").append("<div class=\"error\"><span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement." +
            "style.display='none';\">&times;</span>" + "<h4>Server Returned 500 Error Code</h4>" + "</div>");

            // Show Form Again
            $("#enrollPhase1Container").show();
          }
        }
    })

    .done(function(response) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#animationSpin").addClass("hidden");

            if(response == "REFRESH") {
              location.reload();
            } else if(response.startsWith("Error")) {
              // Error Message Adding
              $(".status").append("<div class=\"error\"><span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">" +
              "&times;</span>" + response.replace("Error", "") + "</div>");

              // Increase height
              $("#loginContainer").height("70%");

              // Show Form Again
              $("#enrollPhase1Container").show();
            } else {
              // Remove UsernameForm...
              $("#enrollPhase1Container").remove();

              // Decrease height
              $("#loginContainer").height("50%");

              // Set the message text.
              $("#login").append(response);
            }
        }, 1000)
    })
});
});
```

#### enrollphase1.php:

```
// Do we have
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(formData)`?

Comment: Im no jquery expert but shouldn't `$(EnrollPhase1Form)` be `EnrollPhase1Form` or `$('#enrollPhase1')` eg `EnrollPhase1Form.attr('method')`

Comment: Doing `$(EnrollPhase1Form)` does seem to be the wrong way to go about passing selectors or selected elements around. Also I noticed a few uses of just `this.something` when those should be `$(this).something`. (also missing a few semicolons, but that shouldn't affect the POST vars)

Comment: However, before you go adjusting anything, give ALL your form elements a `name="some_var_name"`. As even with serialize, you still need a `name` for the post var.

Comment: what did error reporting show? and what was the var_dump's results?

Comment: about your *"many of you do not wish to spend your time answering this long of a question"* - What long question? I didn't see one. I saw me looking at what I would have debugged with error reporting throwing you rocks in the background but you didn't feel a thing. Why? Because, it was there all along, telling you about all of those undefined index errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `name` attribute on all your form elements. They are still required for `.serialize` (so it can give a post variable its name for the value). So adjust your form elements:

```
<form action="/core/enrollphase1.php" id="enrollPhase1" method="post" name="enrollPhase1">
    <select .. id="SecurityQuestion1" name="SecurityQuestion1"></select>
    <input  .. id="SecurityAnswer1"   name="SecurityAnswer1" type="text">
    <select .. id="SecurityQuestion2" name="SecurityQuestion2"></select>
    <input  .. id="SecurityAnswer2"   name="SecurityAnswer2" type="text">
    <input .. type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Now when you get them from the `$_POST` array, you should see them as:

```
$_POST['SecurityQuestion1']
$_POST['SecurityAnswer1']
$_POST['SecurityQuestion2']
$_POST['SecurityAnswer2']
```

As a side note, your usage of selectors in the jquery is a bit, odd. I would suggest you change to the following (for just these lines):

```
$("#enrollPhase1").submit(function(event) {
    ....
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the spot! My problem is I do not know how to really debug JS, so if you have any pointers for that, that would be awesome!

Comment: Debugging js is a multi-headed hydra ;) The best tool is right in your web browser (many browsers, not all!). Open up the 'developer console/tools' which gives you a nice set of tools. You can see what is sent, what is received, raw data, interpolated data, and even console spew (using calls to `console.log( 'something happened!');`). In PHP, you only got incoming data to deal with ... thus your `var_dump` was about all you could do there.

Comment: Another tool I use after writing up a bunch of new js code... is I plop it right into http://jshint.com/ ... and it lets me know of anything really obvious I missed ;)

Comment: I already use developer consoles, but many times they are not perfect.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Something I find useful in the dev tools... is being overly verbose with console.log when something starts going wrong or unexpected. Worst cases, I even put whole element selectors in it, like `console.log( $(this) );` .... lol. So like for your case, you could have done a `console.log( formData );`... alert() tends to ... break. Glad to help, and happy coding.